# Release hash of a repo does not show in its "git log"

Tags: git, git-commit, gitpython

To mine repositories. I'm basically traversing its git commits to extracting info. However, in many repositories, I see that the hash of a release is not present in the git log.

For example in project [bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases), the hash of release v0.19.0.1 is 1bc9988. The git log does not show this commit hash. However, "git log --all" contains this commit hash.

I'd like to know the reasoning behind this. Why is this hash not present in a git log? My mining work is dependent on extracting data from major releases of a project. I'm using PyDriller to do this.

```
from pydriller import RepositoryMining

commits = RepositoryMining(repo_path, only_in_branch=repo_branch).traverse_commits()
for commit in commits:
    // working with a commit
```

How can I get the commits of the major releases?

Comment: `git log`, by default, starts at the *current* commit and works backwards through the commit graph. If the commit you're interested in is not reachable through this backwards traversal, you will not see it. You can tell `git log` to start at other commits, by branch or tag names for instance; `--all` tells `git log` to start at *all* ending-points and work backwards from all of them.

Comment: Why are yoy passing the `only_in_branch` parameter to the `RepositoryMining` constructor? I haven't ever heard of PyDriller, but it certainly looks like this parameter restricts the analyzed commits to the ones in the given branch. So maybe you simply want to omit this parameter?